# Convert Date to Hex to import into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am building a VB.net application that can query a sql server database and then generate insert statements based on the returned results.
I have a case statement that checks the datatype from a combobox and formats it depending on the datatype. The next problem I have and the one I'm asking is, is it possible to convert a date to an integer to a hex value, so that I can cast the hex value to a sql server datetime datatype ? I hope my code is not too noob.

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        x = 0
        Dim splitout = Split(TextBox1.Text, " ")
        builder.Append("INSERT INTO " & splitout(3).ToUpper & " (")
        Do Until x = DataGridView1.Columns.Count
            builder.Append(DataGridView1.Columns(x).HeaderText.ToString)
            If x = DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                builder.Append("")
            Else
                builder.Append(",")
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
        builder.Append(") VALUES (")
        For Each dc As DataColumn In dt.Columns
            Do Until y = dt.Columns.Count
                Select Case ComboBox1.Items(y).ToString
                    Case "char"
                        builder.Append("'" & LTrim(RTrim(dr(y))) & "'")
                    Case "smalldatetime"
                        If dr(y) Is DBNull.Value Then
                            builder.Append("NULL")
                        Else
                            Dim hexbuilder As New StringBuilder
                            Dim var2INT As Integer
                            var2INT = CInt(dr(y))
                            For x = 0 To var2INT.ToString.Length - 1
                                hexbuilder.Append(Conversion.Hex(var2INT.ToString.Substring(x, 1)))
                            Next x
                            builder.Append("CAST(" & hexbuilder.ToString & " as smalldatetime)")
                        End If
                    Case "numeric"
                        builder.Append(dr(y))
                    Case "bit"
                        builder.Append("CAST('" & dr(y) & "' as BIT)")
                    Case "uniqueidentifier"
                        If dr(y) Is DBNull.Value Then
                            builder.Append("NULL")
                        Else
                            builder.Append("N'")
                            builder.Append(dr(y))
                            builder.Append("'")
                        End If
                    Case "varchar"
                        builder.Append("'" & LTrim(RTrim(dr(y))) & "'")
                End Select
                If y = dt.Columns.Count - 1 Then

                Else
                    builder.Append(",")
                End If

                y = y + 1
            Loop
        Next
        builder.Append(")")
        builder.AppendLine()
        y = 0
    Next
    ds.Dispose()
    Con.Close()
```

Comment: Ye gods! At what point do you stop yourself and say "there has to be a better way to do this"? Please look at using [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx).

Comment: Ha ha, It looks like SqlParameters are the way forward then. Thanks guys, I'll go away and look into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know It is not possible to set HEX value of a date. Dates are stored as double.

To set days in SQL queries I use `yyyy-mm-dd` format in string and forced connection language 
`Current Language=us_english`

```
builder.Append(CType(dr(y), Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

You can use use another format with another language.

Comment: Thanks IvanH, it's the format that I needed to avoid but I suppose I could query the connection language to get the date format for the datetime when converting to the string. I didn't know it was stored as a double so that another handy avenue to investigate

Comment: Better would be to use a DateTime variable and a SqlParameter.  Then you don't need to worry about format at all.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway You are right. I usually prefer parameters too but the question was about conversion.